# Can a batsman be run out if he jumps to avoid the ball?

Tags: rules, cricket

If a batsman successfully completes a run but then jumps to avoid the ball, and the ball then hits the stumps while the batsman is in the air, is the batsman out?

Answer (score 6):

The batsman is not out. The exact situation is explained by [law 38](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-38-run-out/) and [law 29.1.b](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-29-batsman-out-of-his-ground/).

As he has made good his ground and then happens to be in the air after doing so, which by the definition of running he must be he will be not out.  This was brought in after the slow motion replays started showing batsmen with both feet in the air despite being in.

In addition, law 38.2.a.i allows the batsmen to leave his ground to avoid injury after making good his ground.

Comment: Note that for Law 29.1(b) to apply, he must have grounded a foot behind the popping crease; merely having grounded his bat is insufficient. This does not affect any application Law 38.2(a)(i), which simply requires his ground to have been made in any normal way.